# What's a quick and dirty way to get "lapsed" members in WordPress configured with s2Member?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I have a default installation of WordPress configured with the membership management plugin known as s2Member.  What is a quick and dirty way to return an array of "lapsed" members?

I assume this information is hidden somewhere in the user's  metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the "demoted" note that s2Member logs:

```
$lapsedMembers = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT
            DISTINCT (`u`.`ID`),
            `u`.`display_name`    `name`,
            `u`.`user_email`      `memberemail`,
            `u`.`user_registered` `enrollmentdate`,
            `um`.`meta_value`     `lapsereason`
        FROM
            {$wpdb->users} u
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} um ON u.ID = um.user_id
        WHERE
            um.meta_key = %s
            AND um.meta_value LIKE % s
    ", 'wp_s2member_notes', '%Demoted%'),
    ARRAY_A
);
```